# How to access a container methods when the container is in a class as a private member?

Tags: c++, containers

I have a simple question. I have a class say A with a private member that is a stl container, for example a vector of ints. Is there a way to use its methods (e.g. size, resize, etc...) ? Does the classic "get function" suffice ?

```
Class A
{
private:
    std::vector<int> v;
public:
    std::vector<int> get_v() {return v;};
};
```

If yes, isn't a "get function" meant to only get the member and not to modify the member ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Basically you just declare the function as `const` and the return value as a `const` reference.

Comment: I seem to have interpreted your question differently to others. Does your last question imply that you *want* to modify the member? Or do you not want that?

Comment: The main question is, if I want to modify the container, its size for example, how do I do that ? But I think Bathsheba solve the problem. I am going to check that immediately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal thing to do here is to return a *constant reference* to the data member:

```
const std::vector<int>& get_v() const
{
    return v;
}
```

Note that I've also made the function constant. This tells you that the function will not modify any data members in the class.

Currently, you are taking a deep copy of the vector, which is expensive in terms of performance and also detaches you from the original data.

If you want to call methods like `resize` (that change the vector) then you can also supply a non-constant version of the function (overloading on `const`) is allowed in C++):

```
std::vector<int>& get_v()
{
    return v;
}
```

The compiler will call the `const` version if you have a `const` pointer (or reference) to an instance of `A`. Else if will call the non-`const` version.

Comment: Although, if you're going to provide a function to access it directly, you might as well give up the pretence of encapsulation and make it public.

Answer (score 0):

That getter will return a copy of the internal vector. Any modifications you make will only affect the copy. That might be okay if you also provide a setter so that the modified copy can be passed back, so you could do something like this:

```
A a;
std::vector<int> v = a.get_v();
v.push_back(5);
a.set_v(v);
```

Alternatively, you can make the getter return a reference to the internal vector (so its return type would be `std::vector<int>&`, then you can modify it from outside.

Answer (score 0):

Your get method returns a copy of the data member. So such a method does not allow to modify the original vector,

If you want to provide an access to elements of the vector you can either overload operator[] or write a get method with a parameter.

For example

```
Class A
{
private:
    std::vector<int> v;
public:
    int operator []( std::vector<int>::size_type n ) const { return v[n]; }
    int & operator []( std::vector<int>::size_type n ) { return v[n]; }
};
```

or you can write get methods that do the same

```
Class A
{
private:
    std::vector<int> v;
public:
    int get( std::vector<int>::size_type n ) const { return v[n]; }
    int & get( std::vector<int>::size_type n ) { return v[n]; }
};
```

As for the idea to use a copy of the vector or a reference to it that to get its size then it is not a good idea. It is better to provide a method that returns the size of the vector. In this case the user interface will not depend on the type of the container.